# Extract years between Two dates and add Custom Label

Tags: excel, vba

the below VBA code is extracting the Month and Year, is there possible to get only the year and custom string in the adjacent column as Year1, Year2...

**Expected results**
Year Label

2020 Year1
2021 Year2

```
`Sub ExtractYears()
'
 Dim sc As Range
 Dim Stdt As Date
 Dim Edt As Date
 Dim dDate As Date
 Dim off As Integer
'
 Stdt = Range("B1") ' start date
 Edt = Range("B2") ' end date
 Set sc = Range("c2") ' start cell
'
' To clear the existing contents in Range D2 till end
 Range("c2").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.ClearContents

'Offset
 off = 0
'
 For dDate = Stdt To Edt
    If Format(dDate, "dd") <= "01" Then
      sc.Offset(off, 0) = Format(dDate, "mmmm yyyy")
      off = off + 1
    End If
 Next dDate

'
sc.Resize(off, 1).NumberFormat = "mmmm yyyy"
'
End Sub
```

`
Thank you for your time and suggestions

[ExcelView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mniQ2.jpg)

Comment: Can you please show an example how this should look inside the sheet?

Comment: Thank you Dariusz Sokoi im not able to upload the excel file, however i have attached the Picture of excel sheet. If any way you would like me to send the file via email. kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've embedded some extra code into the existing code

```
Sub ExtractYears()
'
 Dim sc As Range
 Dim Stdt As Date
 Dim Edt As Date
 Dim dDate As Date
 Dim off As Integer
 Dim offY As Integer
 Dim year As Integer
'
 Stdt = Range("B1") ' start date
 Edt = Range("B2") ' end date
 Set sc = Range("c2") ' start cell
'
' To clear the existing contents in Range D2 till end
 Range("c2").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.ClearContents
Columns("F:G").ClearContents
'Offset
 off = 0
 offY = 0
'
 For dDate = Stdt To Edt
    If Format(dDate, "dd") <= "01" Then
        year = Format(dDate, "yyyy")
        sc.Offset(off, 0) = Format(dDate, "mmmm yyyy")
        If sc.Offset(offY, 3) = vbNullString Or sc.Offset(offY, 3).Value = year Then
            sc.Offset(offY, 3) = year
            sc.Offset(offY, 4) = "Year" & offY + 1
        Else
            offY = offY + 1
            sc.Offset(offY, 3) = year
            sc.Offset(offY, 4) = "Year" & offY + 1
        End If
        off = off + 1
    End If
 Next dDate

'
sc.Resize(off, 1).NumberFormat = "mmmm yyyy"
'
End Sub
```